# Ordernar un array de objetos en base a otro arreglo

Tags: javascript, array

Lo que estoy trantando de hacer es ordernar un array de objetos en base a otro array que me dira el orden los keys del arreglo que quiero ordenar, por ejemplo:

```
const source = [{ id: 1, perro: "dog", gato: "cat" }]; // arreglo que quiero ordenar

const order = ["gato", "id", "perro"]; // este es el orden en que tiene que quedar
```

el resultado tendria que ser algo asi:

```
const newSource = [{ gato: 'cat', id: 1, perro: 'dog'}];
```

Intente algo como lo siguiente, ordena el array , pero cada item lo pone en un objeto independiente y deberia :

```
const t = source.map(i => {
  return order.map(j => {
    return {
      [j]: i[j]
    }
  })
})
```

esto me genera la siguiente salida:

```
[[{"gato": "cat"},{"id": 1},{"perro": "dog"}]]
```

como pueden ver, lo ordena, pero cada item esta en un objeto diferente y lo que necesito es que esten en un solo los 3 items.

Comment: El ordenamiento no lo decides tu, es algo que lo deciden los objetos al crearse, hagas lo que hagas no puedes ordenar un objeto como tu quieras, puesto que al parsearlo el orden sera como javascript le de la gana, de hecho el orden normalmente es alfanumerico, primero los valores con claves numericas y luego los valores literales ordenados alfabeticamente, de todas maneras no es necesario ordenar un objeto, puesto que puedes acceder a sus propiedades de manera desordenada sin problemas, solo necesitas conocer la clave que desees acceder del objeto.

Comment: Ademas, a no ser de que tengas indices numericos en tu objeto, si tu idea es usar un objeto a manera de poder acceder a sus valores como un array, no se podria de manera directa, puesto que un array no es lo mismo que un objeto, sus metodos, propiedades y formas de recorrerlos son diferentes, y aun peor, si tienes claves que no sean numericas entonces directamente no puedes accederlo mediante indices numericos.

Comment: De hecho hay que aclarar una cosa... tu NO tienes un arreglo de objetos, tienes un arreglo de un objeto, repercute en el hecho de que no hay objetos que ordenar si el objeto es solo 1, ya que el objeto puede tener diferentes llaves y valores, como lo pintas en el codigo, pero esas llaves y propiedades hacen parte de ese unico objeto que tienes, cada una no es un objeto en si.